# Problem during installation of ruby version 2.7.2 in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, permissions, ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails

Hope you all are doing well. I am working on Ubuntu linux 20.04 I am beginner to ruby. I have installed rvm. Now I am trying to install ruby version 2.7.2 but It is giving me an error again and again.

[image]

I could not get why this is happening. Can somebody help to solve it out.

In the image you can see the error that i have been facing during installation. First it gives me:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied
```

And then:

```
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
There was an error(23). 
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions with your current user in the directory `/usr/share/rvm/rubies`?